# Can I change User table structure in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to change the default structure of laravel's user table. I successfully migrated the table but when i'm trying to add record into it, it gives me the following error eventhough i passed all the data!
[image]

Comment: Can you show us , what you have tried?

Comment: User::create(["name" => $request->name , "email"=>$request->email,"password"=>$request->password,"user_level_id"=> 1, "parent_user_id"=> \Auth::user()->id]);

Comment: I have these columns in my database for users table (`id`, `name`, `email`, `user_level_id`, `parent_user_id`, `password`, `remember_token`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)

Comment: See if there's anything here that may solve your problem: https://laravel.io/forum/08-08-2015-eloquent-create-says-column-has-no-default-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like  you need to set all columns as fillable, do this in the model:

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

or for selective column

```
protected $fillable = [
       name, email, user_level_id, parent_user_id, password
    ];
```

Comment: Cool that works !! Now i have one question. Should't I get Mass assignment error for this fillable ?